# What to do about a gas leak on my air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have an air conditioner that displays an error of gas leakage on the board.

What should I do? Shall I turn it off? It is dangerous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a leak of coolant gas.  Though I've never had an AC with indicators like this, what's the model?  It will eventually force the compressor to shut itself off or else the compressor would burn up from lack of lubrication (which is also included in the coolant).  At which point, the AC will no longer work.  You need to find the leak and fix it, then have the system recharged.  Since the coolant likely isn't available without a license in your area, you'll need a contractor for this.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the model is "wall mounted" air conditioner buyed from International Co. for Engineering Industries & Air Conditioning, actually it display an error E5 - gas leakage. So I turn it off till company will come to see what's wrong.